# gmail phishing scam - how is the information captured?

Tags: data-uri

In this Fortune article - http://fortune.com/2017/01/18/google-gmail-scam-phishing/ - they say:

> As soon as a person enters her username and password into the fields,
>   the attackers capture the information.

What do they mean by "the attackers capture the information"?  Is there a script that captures the username and password and then posts the data (over HTTP, TCP, etc) to the hacker's server somewhere?

Curious to know the details.

Answer (score 0):

This hack involves creating an entire page using the just URL.  That means the attacker fully controls what you see and what the page does.  Presumably the attackers have a server set-up somewhere and the html form action and/or some AJAX request points to their server.